# How to create an ASP.NET website in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am creating an application using VS 2019 and Web API (.NET Framework). I need to create a blank website, but getting only web application project template. Is there any tools do i need to be installed? Please check the below image to understand my need.

**VS 2017**

[image]

**VS 2019**

[image]

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To create "ASP.NET Web Site" projects in Visual Studio 2019 you need to install the "Additional project templates (previous versions)" ASP.NET Component as shown below.

I have to confess I'd missed this option too as it's only visible if you click on the ASP.NET workload and is not listed on the "Individual components" tab!

[image]

After installing the component, the templates are now present:

[image]

Comment: Damn this was hidden well. Nice find!

Comment: Thank You! Very useful answer. This is hidden away.

Comment: I was going crazy until I found this solution.  What a well-hidden option.