# Setting CodeFile by default in Visual Studio Community 2019

Tags: c#, installation, default

Because this is an educational environment I must use CodeFile rather than CodeBehind.

Is there a way to use CodeFile by default rather than CodeBehind in Visual Studio Community 2019.

Comment: If you create a [Website project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58224003/how-to-create-an-asp-net-website-in-visual-studio-2019) instead of web application, you'll get CodeFile by default in that project.

Comment: Thanks!  Will give that a try.