# Which IDE for VB.NET code built on .NET framework 2.5?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I used to use MS `Visual Web Development (VWD) Express 2008` as IDE for a website which was developed on `.NET framework 2.5` with `VB.NET` and runs on `IIS 7` originally. About a year ago, MS stopped downloading the VWD Express 2008 and now I am in need of an IDE for my old VB.NET website. Which `IDE` will allow me to maintain this old VB.NET website?

Here is the detail info of VS 2019 community installed:

[image]

Here is screen shot of the existing project I am maintaining.

[image]

Comment: [Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition ISO](https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/B/5/8B5804AD-4990-40D0-A6AA-CE894CBBB3DC/VS2008ExpressENUX1397868.iso) and [Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1](https://download.microsoft.com/download/a/3/7/a371b6d1-fc5e-44f7-914c-cb452b4043a9/VS2008SP1ENUX1512962.iso)

Comment: Ok, that looks good!!! - see my two new screen shots below - are you trying to create a new project, or open existing?

Comment: I am open an existing project. Just posted the screen shot for my project page. It is a website but I am not sure how it is called in VB. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with Visual Studio Express.
(edit: It is now called Visual Studio Community Edition).

It should work fine. To be honest, I never used Visual Web Developer.

Just keep in mind, that you want to open the project as a web site, and NOT a project. Quite sure that's how VW developer worked and was setup.

I'm not even sure they have VW developer anymore, but Visual Studio Express 2019 should be able to open + work on that web site.

So, to open a web application project, then you use this option:
(this means you have a .sln file).

So this:

[image]

However, this might ONLY be a web site project. So, you can use this option:

[image]

So, I would certinly try to open the project (folder) where the site exists, and see if you can find a .sln file.

If there is no .sln file, then you can try to open the .vbproj file.

But if you open a "web site", then you ONLY select the folder where the web site exists. (you don't open .sln, or .vbproj file - but open the FOLDER.

Comment: There is no Express version for 2019, the last Express version is 2017 and it's the Desktop variant only without support for web apps. The 2015 Express Web version is still downloadable.

Comment: I meant to say Visual Studio Community 2019. (so, it sort of called Express, but the real name is Community edition, and they don't use the name "Express" anymore).

Comment: There's a license difference though, it's not a problem for most independent dev who are eligible for Community, but those on corps without license purchase are either supposed to stay on Express or move to Code if possible.

Comment: I installed VS 2019 community and spent quite some time trying to figure out how to use. But I didn't find option of open an website and there is no `build website`.

Comment: I see build in my web web sites. And I also see build  if you creating + using a web application. So both web sites, and web applications are supported.

Comment: Very possible I miss something with the VS which I am not familiar with.

Comment: I see your new screen shot  --- that looks good, so I added two new screen caps to my post. Are you attempting to open an existing project, or trying to create a new web project from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

VS 2017 is the last one that [explicitly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2017/vs2017-compatibility-vs#-visual-studio-2017-support-for-net-development) mention supports for .NET 3.5, and the [Community](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202017&wt.mc_id=o%7Emsft%7Evscom%7Eolder-downloads) version is still available with the free Dev Essentials account. If you're ineligible for Community, then the [Visual Studio Express 2015 for Web](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202015%20web&wt.mc_id=o%7Emsft%7Evscom%7Eolder-downloads) is the one you want.

That said, even in the latest VS 2022, I still see the option to switch a project to target .NET 3.5, and the template still offers Web Form development.

Comment: Shall try VS 2022 community? I tried VS community 2017(desktop)/2019 and didn't find support for VB.NET website.

Comment: I'm currently using vs2019 and asp.net + vb.net. There are additonal templates you can download. As noted, VS is now a very large product. But yes, it has full support for vb.net, and asp.net web sites.

Comment: @user938363 Can you confirm that it is a *community* version instead of Express? If you scroll down the new project page there's an option to [add workloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio), make sure you include the ASP.NET development and on the optional section, add the .NET 3.5 SDK

Comment: `Martheen`, I just uploaded the detail info about the VS 2019 community installed.

Comment: @user938363 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58224003/how-to-create-an-asp-net-website-in-visual-studio-2019/58239052

Comment: `Martheen`, many thanks. you have provided critical information to nail down VS 2019 community as the IDE.